# Select parents based on all children statisfying condition

Tags: mysql

This is such a simple problem but for some reason I cannot get my head round it today.

I have two entities:- `title` and `product` each respectively named `tbl_title` and `tbl_product`. Each `title` can have many `products`.

The product table has a field called `unwanted` which can be either `null`, `0` or `1`.

I wish to select all `title`s based on where all `product`s (ALL) have `unwanted` set to `1`. So in other words I wish to select the parent based upon all children filling a certain condition. So if a `title` has one `product` that is `unwanted` but another that is not I do not wish for this `title` to enter the result set.

When I try this the most I get out of my head is:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_title` 
    left join tbl_product on tbl_product.title_id = tbl_title.id 
    where tbl_product.unwanted = 1 
    group by tbl_title.id
```

Which obviously does not work.

So how do I code such a query?

Comment: Your description differs from your title. Should all children have the condition or just one

Comment: @juergend All children I describe "all" in title and in description

Comment: `So if a title has one product that is unwanted but another than is not I do wish for this title to enter the result set.` What does that mean?

Comment: @juergend Whoops your right, I was meant to say "that" rather than "than"

Comment: Never mind. But I think it should be: So if a title has one product that is unwanted but another than is not I do wish for this title **not** to enter the result set.

Comment: @juergend omg I am so fail today, yea your right...again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from tbl_title
where id not in (select title_id from tbl_product where unwanted = 0)
```

In English, this query eliminates all titles that have a wanted product.

From a style point of view, it would be better to call your column `wanted`, because `unwanted = 0` is a double-negative of `wanted = 1`. It's always easier to get your head around positives.

Comment: I am gonna need to test this because if one title id has both an unwanted product and a wanted product under would it not return a title_id from the sub select?

Comment: @Sammaye No. The presence of any `unwanted = 0` will cause that title to not be selected. This query however will return titles that have no products whatsoever. If that's not your intention, let me know - it can be easily fixed

Comment: Indeed since of course you are going on title_id, I didn't see that, after some tweaking and testing it seems to return exactly 7 more results than the answers above, I will need to test this out and find out which is best, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.id 
FROM `tbl_title` t
left join tbl_product p on p.title_id = t.id 
group by t.id
having sum(p.unwanted = 0 or p.unwanted is null) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a subquery like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_title` AS t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products WHERE title_id = t.id AND unwanted = 1)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products WHERE title_id = t.id AND (unwanted = 0 OR unwanted IS NULL))
```

Comment: Somebody who doesnt understand `EXISTS` have downvoted this. This works and there is nothing wrong.

Comment: +1 to counter. Also you can use `*` instead of `1` inside the inner select as it makes no difference..

Comment: Although a lot slower than juergen's answer (and a lot heavier) it does return EXACTLY the same results.

Comment: @Sammaye did you test it? EXISTS doesn't do full table scans.

Comment: Yea I got a spike in load, now that I look into it, I ran it agan with the load off and it is about 0.01 sec slower which is nothing.

Comment: The 1 instead of * is a holdover from my Oracle days where it hurt performance to use *. In MySQL the two are equivalent as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fields in `title` table

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     `tbl_title` AS t
JOIN     tbl_product AS v ON t.id = v.title_id
WHERE    NOT EXISTS(
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM   tbl_product 
                    WHERE  (t.id = title_id) 
                       AND (unwanted = 0 OR unwanted IS NULL)
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: I think this still suffers from the same problem as Kaii's answer whereby the subselect will bring back the incorrect results. It would work for titles that only have one product that is unwanted under them but it wouldn't work for multiples.

Comment: @Sammaye some wrong understanding I guess. I tested this now and it works. Did you try?

Comment: @Sammaye you're right this brings unwanted records but you phrased it wrongly. I will delete this because if I correct this it will become exaclty davidethell's answer